# Using the REST API of Twilio

Tags: java, http, rest, twilio

Not being familiar with REST and after reading some doc about it I am a little bit confused about the way it works.

I actually want to use Twilio SMS Gateway that provides a REST API to interact with and send text messages from an existing web-application.

From what I understand, REST is a way to structure a web service and in the end, instead of using SOAP for example, we just access 'resources' with URLs, relying on HTTP to GET, PUT or DELETE data.

The SMS Gateway I am talking about is providing a Java API that I could integrate to my web-app. The classes in this API uses httpcore, httpclient and commons-codec jars. Is this because REST rely on HTTP?

So basically, their API is relying on the Apache and HTTP libs to construct HTTP requests in Java and setting the basics, so I just have to provide with the data I want to submit and/or specific information?

Answer (score 1):

REST API's are HTTP API's. The word *REST* is supposed to indicate something about how your API works. Basically that you use POST requests to update data and GET requests to retrieve it, and you have different HTTP endpoints for all of the different resources in your API, like Calls or Recordings.

The Twilio helper libraries (including the Java library) are basically wrappers around HTTP calls to the Twilio API. The idea was to make it easier for you to make API calls to Twilio by abstracting away the HTTP authentication and request stuff behind some more language-specific code. We also parse the HTTP response into an object for you.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your clear answer. So if I correctly understand from the doc that I read, in order to use REST, you need to have a server that support it and make it available as a service (for example a Java app with JAX-RS, or Twilio in my case) and then, on my side, I need to use a REST Client to make the request (such as JAX-RS since it can be used to implement a client or a server). Or I could also use the Apache libs as the Twilio helper is already doing. XML or JSON can be different format in which I can ask the answers from the server, Am I correct on those points? What is Jersey?

Comment: Hi, That sounds correct; you need a server to that Twilio can fetch instructions about what to do when you get an inbound call or SMS, and you need an HTTP client to make HTTP requests to the Twilio API. I'm not sure what Jersey is.